Word to PDF file corruption issue
Recently, I was doing the word to pdf problem in Java, using the jar package com.documents4j, the conversion prompted me that the file was corrupted, in fact, the file can be opened normally; with the help of my manager, I tried to delete the word footer, adjust the margins, and then the conversion was successful. Because it's a jar package, there's no way to debug, and a lot of word content won't rewrite the content of the file.
 public static void WordToPdfPoi(String inFilePath,String outPutFilePath) throws Exception {
        File inputWord = new File(inFilePath);
        File outputFile = new File(outPutFilePath);
        try  {
            InputStream docxInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputWord);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();
            converter.convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("success");
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
  
    }

this kind of file corruption problem, how to locate where the problem is.
